# How to determine how much time it will take to finish a cell expression?

Tags: evaluation, timing

I am trying to integrate a large matrix with elements that contain trigonometric expressions. The evaluation is taking a long time--4 days, and it is still running.

Is there anything I can do to find out how much time will it take to finish task?

Comment: In general, there is no way to reliably predict how long a symbolic execution may take, and without additional details there isn't much that can be said. However, here's a piece of advice that you may find helpful when trying to integrate a matrix of symbolic expressions: *don't do it*. Instead, do the integral matrix-element-by-matrix-element. There are two reasons for this: first, if one of the matrix elements is badly-behaved on integration (takes too long, too much RAM, crashes the kernel, etc.) then you lose ALL the matrix element integrals that have previously been calculated.

Comment: The second reason is that in the event that one of the matrix elements is causing problems, then you will have *no idea which element of the array is causing trouble*. In summary, doing it element-by-element prevents results from being destroyed (and thus often saves time) *and* assists in debugging. By isolating which part of your array is causing difficulty, you will have a far easier time diagnosing and fixing problems.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Thanks for the help you have given.  It has really made me think twice. I have matrix integration over size 72*72. I should do the integral matrix-element-by-matrix-element. However, I am sure enough that none of the matrix elements are badly behaved. As they all are quadratic expressions of trigonometric expression. So it makes sense that none of the matrix element will cause any problem. Hence, here the question arises on time. Should I go for whole integration or element by element considering that my elements are well behaved. Waiting for your answer, sir. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need symbolic results from the integration, or can you use `NIntegrate`?

Comment: Maybe try: [halting problem fix](https://xkcd.com/1266/).

Comment: As a broad suggestion for a vague question: is there any redundancy in the calculation you can use to speed things up? Any structure in the matrix for instance. Also, always do element by element, and save the results as you go. Maybe print some info letting you know where you are in the calculation so you know it's still progressing. You say there aren't any badly behaved elements, but what if you wait four days for a typo?